# Play Framework: How to convert strings to numbers while validating JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON..

```
{
    "ask":"428.00",
    "bid":"424.20"
}
```

... I need to convert the values of `ask` and `bid` to numbers:

```
{
    "ask": 428.00,
    "bid": 424.20
}
```

To do that, I've created a validator that reads the string value and passes it to method `toNumber`, which validates and converts the given string:

```
def validate = (
  ((__ \ 'ask).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString] <~ toNumber)) ~
  ((__ \ 'bid).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsString] <~ toNumber))
).reduce

private def toNumber(implicit reads: Reads[String]) = {
  Reads[Double](js =>
    reads.reads(js).flatMap { value =>
      parse[Double](value) match {
        case Some(number) => JsSuccess(number)
        case _ => JsError(ValidationError("error.number", value))
      }
    }
  )
}
```

The code above only validates the value but of course does not replace the original string with the converted number. How do I convert string values to numbers while validating?

**EDIT**

Just wanted to share the solution provided by Ben:

```
def validate = (
  ((__ \ 'ask).json.update(toNumber)) ~
  ((__ \ 'bid).json.update(toNumber))
).reduce

private def toNumber(implicit reads: Reads[String]) = {
  Reads[JsNumber](js =>
    reads.reads(js).flatMap { value =>
      parse[Double](value) match {
        case Some(number) => JsSuccess(JsNumber(number))
        case _ => JsError(ValidationError("error.number", value))
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to do that in one step? (Do you want a `Try`/`Either` as a result? I think the validation's result is not suitable for this task.)

Comment: ... in case I could verify that strings actually contain numbers... and then convert the whole JSON...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make `toNumber` a `Reads[JsNumber]` instead of a `Reads[Double]` (simply by wrapping `number` in `JsNumber`), then you can use `transform` together with `update`:

```
val transformer = (__ \ "ask").json.update(toNumber)
val json = Json.parse(""" { "ask" : "44" } """)
json.transorm(transformer) //JsSuccess({"ask":44.0},/ask)

val json = Json.parse(""" { "ask" : "foo" } """)
json.transorm(transformer) //JsError(List((/ask,List(ValidationError(error.number,WrappedArray(foo))))))
```

In a sense, transformers *are* validators.  Instead of checking if something is valid, and then transforming it, you can use `transform` to simply transform the value, and get a `JsError` if the transformation is invalid.  Read more about `transform` [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonTransformers).

Comment: Thank you very much! I've updated my post with your solution.