# Play Framework: Converting strings to numbers while validating JSON does not work

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON...

```
{
    "ask":"428.00",
    "bid":"424.20"
}
```

... I need to convert the values of `ask` and `bid` to numbers:

```
{
    "ask": 428.00,
    "bid": 424.20
}
```

As already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695520/play-framework-how-to-convert-strings-to-numbers-while-validating-json/29699082#29699082), I just need to create a validator like this:

```
def validate = (
  ((__ \ 'ask).json.update(toNumber)) ~
  ((__ \ 'bid).json.update(toNumber))
).reduce

private def toNumber(implicit reads: Reads[String]) = {
  Reads[JsNumber](js =>
    reads.reads(js).flatMap { value =>
      parse[Double](value) match {
        case Some(number) => JsSuccess(JsNumber(number))
        case _ => JsError(ValidationError("error.number", value))
      }
    }
  )
}
```

The problem is that only the last node (`bid`) gets actually converted to a number... and the resulting JSON looks like this:

```
}
    "ask":"428.00",
    "bid":424.20
}
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Using `andThen` only works if the JSON structure only contains strings to convert to numbers... whereas if the JSON structure already contains numeric fields it doesn't. Given the following JSON [`last` is already numeric]:

```
}
    "ask":"428.00",
    "bid":"424.20",
    "last": 430.05
}
```

If I modify my validator like this [replaced `~` with `andThen` and removed `reduced`]...

```
def validate = (
  ((__ \ 'ask).json.update(toNumber)) andThen
  ((__ \ 'bid).json.update(toNumber)) andThen
  ((__ \ 'last).json.pickBranch(Reads.of[JsNumber]))
)
```

... then I get the following error when trying to validate my JSON above:

```
JsError(List((/bid/last,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))))
```

Comment: I hate all that applicative stuff in play-json, because when it doesn't work, the implementation is totally opaque - at least to me.  I am no expert, but when I've had this kind of problem in play-json it's because I've used some combining idiom that throws away the left side - in this case, "~".  Review the docs to see if maybe you should be using some other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing [the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/ScalaJsonTransformers), it looks like you should be using "andThen", not "~".  See "Case 7".

Comment: If this turns out to be correct, consider renaming the post to something like "...combined updates not working..." so that other folks who have the same problem are more likely to find it.

Comment: It works partially... if the Json structure only contains strings to convert to numbers, then it works... but if the Json structure contains both strings to convert and number, then it doesn't - see my updated post.

Comment: @j3d I'm no expert, but I can't figure out what you're trying to do with the pickbranch.

Comment: pickBranch just extracts a JsPath + its JsValue

Comment: @j3d I know what *it* does, I can't figure out what *you're* trying to do with it. If you didn't include it at all, you'd get ask/bid/last as numbers, which I thought was what you wanted.

Comment: The real use-case is that an external system invokes a callback on my servers and I need to verify incoming JSON is formatted correctly (i.e. amounts are actually numbers, date formats, etc.). In the example in this post I use `pickBranch` to ensure `last` is a numeric value. The problem in the real use-case is that incoming JSON is not always 100% consistent since some numbers are represented like `"number1": 150.55` while some others like `"number2":"250.65"`. That's why I need to converted some values to numbers and verify some others are actually numeric.